# How do you increase Internet Explorer 7's "Select as you type" timeout for comboboxes?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, combobox, timeout, registry

In Internet Explorer 7, you can select options from comboboxes by typing the first few letters of the value you're looking for. However, some people in our organisation are a bit slow and can't type their selection quick enough, with the result that the timeout is triggered and the "select as you type" process starts all over again.

Example:
If I type A-R-M-A (looking for Armadale) then wait half a second and type D, I'll get selections beginning with the letter D.

What I want to do is increase this timeout to allow for slow typers. (We're in a corporate environment so rolling out these changes to all machines won't be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

These timeouts are quite often connected with double-click times. Increase it and check whether timeout changes.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/04/23/8417521.aspx

Comment: Wow, great thinking! Unfortunately it didn't work in this situation :(